# Word Transformation by changing 1 letter at a time bug

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I have written a program which will show whether a word can be transformed into another by changing a single character at a time, while the intermediate words are also valid words.

For e.g CAT->COT -> DOT-> DOC

The program works when I use `LinkedHashSet` to represent the vertices
but it goes into an infinite loop or wrong answer when I use `HashSet`.

I would like to know what is the problem and if there is a better way to solve the problem then please tell me.

Here is the code: Split into 3 files:
Graph.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

public class Graph {

    private Set<GraphNode> vertices;

    public Graph() {
        //the code runs when I use LinkedHashSet
        vertices = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        //the code goes into infinite loop or wrong answer when I use HashSet to represent the vertices
        //************

        //vertices = new HashSet<>();

        //*************
        //^^^^^ strange behaviour
    }

    /**
     * adds all the words from the given dictonary to the graph
     * @param dictonary
     * @return
     */
    public boolean addAll(Set<String> dictonary){
        boolean result= false;

        for (String word : dictonary){
            addNode(word);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * add a single node into the graph
     * @param data
     * @return
     */
    public GraphNode addNode(String data){
        GraphNode node = new GraphNode();
        node.setValue(data);
        vertices.add(node);
        return node;
    }

    /**
     * add a neighbour to the "source" node
     * @param source
     * @param neighbour
     * @return
     */
    public boolean addNeighbour(GraphNode source, GraphNode neighbour) {
        boolean result = false;
        source.getNeighbours().add(neighbour);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * This method assigns the neighbours of nodes depending on whether they are one edit
     * away or not
     */
    public void assignNeighbours(){

        ArrayList<GraphNode> listOfNodes = getAllVertices();

        Set<String> usedWords = new HashSet<>();
        for ( int i=0 ;i <listOfNodes.size() ;i++){
            String currentWord = listOfNodes.get(i).value;
            for (int j=0 ; j < listOfNodes.size() ;j++ ){
                if (currentWord.equals(listOfNodes.get(j).value)==false){
                    if (oneEditAway(currentWord, listOfNodes.get(j).value) && usedWords.contains(listOfNodes.get(j).value)==false){
                        listOfNodes.get(i).neighbours.add(listOfNodes.get(j));
                        //reflective 
                        listOfNodes.get(j).neighbours.add(listOfNodes.get(i));
                        usedWords.add(listOfNodes.get(j).value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<GraphNode> getAllVertices(){
        return new ArrayList<>(vertices);
    }

    /**
     * This method determines whether 2 strings are one edit away or not
     * @param first
     * @param second
     * @return
     */
    public  boolean oneEditAway(String first, String second) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (first == null || second == null)
            return false;
        if (Math.abs(first.length() - second.length())>1){
            return false;
        }else{
            int firstLength = first.length();
            int secondLength = second.length();
            int mismatchCount = 0;
            for (int i=0 ;i < firstLength && i < secondLength ; ++i){
                if (first.charAt(i) != second.charAt(i)){
                    mismatchCount++;
                }
            }
            if (mismatchCount > 1 || Math.abs(firstLength - secondLength) == 1){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method prints the graph and the connections
     */
    public void printGraph() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (GraphNode node :vertices){
            System.out.println("Node is :"+node.value);
            System.out.println("Neighbours are :");
            for (GraphNode graphNode : node.getNeighbours()){
                System.out.print(graphNode.value+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function determines whether a word can be transformed into an another or not
     * @param source
     * @param dest
     * @return
     */
    public boolean canTransform(String source, String dest) {
        boolean result = false;


        Set<GraphNode> visited = new HashSet<>();

        //BFS is the way to go
        Queue<GraphNode> allNodes = new LinkedList<>();
        GraphNode root=null;
        //find the source node in the graph
        for (GraphNode node : vertices){
            if (node.value.equals(source)){
                root = node;
            }
        }
        allNodes.add(root);
        System.out.println("***************");
        while(!allNodes.isEmpty()){

            GraphNode currentNode = allNodes.poll();

            System.out.println(currentNode.value);
            visited.add(currentNode);
            if (currentNode.value.equals(dest)){
                result = true;
                break;
            }
            for (GraphNode node: currentNode.getNeighbours()){
                if (visited.contains(node) == false){
                    allNodes.add(node);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Graph  is as follows :\nvertices=" + vertices + "";
    }

    public Set<GraphNode> getVertices() {
        return vertices;
    }
    public void setVertices(Set<GraphNode> vertices) {
        this.vertices = vertices;
    }
    }
```

---

Here is the GraphNode.java

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class GraphNode {

    String value;

    Set<GraphNode> neighbours =  new HashSet<GraphNode>();

    public GraphNode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public GraphNode(String value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        GraphNode other = (GraphNode) obj;
        if (value == null) {
            if (other.value != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GraphNode [value=" + value + ", neighbours=" + neighbours + "]";
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Set<GraphNode> getNeighbours() {
        return neighbours;
    }

    public void setNeighbours(Set<GraphNode> neighbours) {
        this.neighbours = neighbours;
    }

}
```

---

Here is the driver class:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class GraphMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        Set<String> dict = new HashSet<>();
        dict.add("CAT");
        dict.add("COT");
        dict.add("DOT");
        dict.add("DOG");
        dict.add("DOC");
        graph.addAll(dict);
        graph.assignNeighbours();
        graph.printGraph();
        String source="CAT",dest = "DOC";
        System.out.println("can transform from "+source+" to "+dest+" ??"+graph.canTransform(source,dest));
    }
}
```

Comment: The **only** difference between `HashSet` and `LinkedHashSet` is that `LinkedHashSet` maintains insertion order. I presume you need the `Collection` to preserve insertion order.

Comment: @BoristheSpider : Perfect. I think that shouldn't affect the code. But it is. That is what has amazed me

Comment: @AneeshK It shouldn't affect your code. If it does - it's a bug. Quite hard to debug this wall of code though..Make sure insertions works fine, and narrow done where the problem exactly is.

Answer (score 0):

The method determining the neighbours of a word is incorrect as the use of the Set `usedWords` is incorrect. The relation `neighbour(w1,w2)` must be independent of the order the neighbours are determined, so using some state to decide whether one word is the neighbour of another one cannot be correct.

```
public void assignNeighbours(){
    for ( GraphNode w1: vertices ){
        for ( GraphNode w2: vertices ){
            if (! w1.equals(w2) ){
                if (oneEditAway(w1.getValue(), w2.getValue())){
                    w1.neighbours.add(w2);
                    //reflective 
                    w2.neighbours.add(w1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```